# Does expanding arraylist of objects make a new object?

Tags: c#, oop, object, arraylist

Assume we have an array list of type Employe , does expanding it's length by 1 make a new object in the list ?

is the code in else statement correct? and is it recommended?

```
    public void ModifierEmp(int c)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Ann.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Ann[i].Code == c)
            {
                Ann[i].saisie();
            } else
            {
                i = Ann.Count + 1; //expanding arraylist ann 
                Ann[i].saisie(); //saisie a method for the user to input Employe infos
            }
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObdO1.jpg "code snippet"

Comment: Please paste full code snippet in the post body.

Comment: `i = Ann.Count + 1` does not do what the comment says. Why did you think it does that?

Comment: i receives the ann.count +1 ;
so when ann .count  = 10
i receives 11 and write new employe infos in that new index

Comment: StriplingWarrior has explained what's really happening, but you should now step through the code and observe the effect for yourself.  Examine the value of `i` each time through the loop and see how changes in the value over time do something different than what you expected. Use different data (matching element at the start of the list, matching element in the middle, and so on) to see different effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = Ann.Count + 1;
```

The code above is not expanding the list: it is only setting your index variable (`i`) to have a new value.

If you wanted to make the list bigger, you would have to tell it which object to put into that new space you create. For example:

```
Ann.Add(anotherItem);
```

Of course, this gives you the ability to decide whether to add an *existing* item, create a new item (e.g. `Ann.Add(new Something() { Code = c })`), or even add a `null` value to the list (which is not usually a good idea).

Comment: so , how can i add new employe dynamically to the list in the else statement?

Comment: Maybe something like `Ann.Add(new Employee(c))`.

Comment: I think you're trying to see whether the list contains any employees with the given code, and add a new employee if it doesn't. The code you've got won't do that, if you think carefully about how your `for` loop logic works. You could instead do something like `if(Ann.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == c) is Employee matched) {matched.saisie();} else {var newEmployee = new Employee(code); Ann.Add(newEmployee); newEmployee.saisie();` and avoid the loop entirely.

Comment: You might also want to look into using a `Dictionary` with employees keyed on the Code property, since that structure is designed for looking up items with a specific key.